# Visa-free Travel Route on a Pakistani Passport

Tags: visas, air-travel, pakistani-citizens, visa-free-entry

According to Wikipedia, there are a number of countries which allow Pakistanis visa-free travel, e-visa or visa on arrival. But none of those countries have direct flights from Pakistan and all the countries that you transit through require transit visa.

Also, I have been told that I cannot board a flight without a valid visa, although I suspect.

So, is there a way to travel visa-free from Pakistan (on a Pakistani passport) to any other country? I mean just book a flight (or multiple flights) and fly away, nothing else needed!

**Edit 11 Aug**

Actually, I don't really have any source showing that all the countries require transit visa, so I might be wrong about that.

I mean any kind of flights; direct or connect, any airline(s).

I am concerned that the airlines will ask for a visa before boarding the flight. Won't they? I cannot just book a flight and fly of to, let's say, Canada. There must be some visa-checking at some point. Wouldn't it be?

Jeju Island in South Korea has visa-free access. But the possible flight route with Qatar Airways will be from Pakistan to Doha to Seoul to Jeju. Will I be asked for a visa if board that flight?

In case of the Pacific nations, which don't require a visa, the transit route is through Hong Kong.

Comment: Direct flights only ? Also, what do you suspect ?

Comment: Given that only a very small number of countries allow visa-free entry to Pakistani citizens, this doesn't surprise me.

Comment: The passport, visa and health rules for every country are stored in a system called Timatic. Airlines use this system when you check in for your flight to determine if you have the right documents. On this web site, you will find that many answers contain links to Timatic results (including my own answer below).

Comment: @MichaelHampton What if a country requires visa but the requirement is not listed on Timatic? Chile, for instance. Does that mean the visa is not actually required or the airline won't ask for it?

Comment: @dngs But Timatic _does_ list Chile, and says a Visa is required. (Which means you must obtain it in advance.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bahrain issues e-visas. There are several ISB-BAH flights, several LHE-BAH flights and one KHI-BAH flight, each day.

I think those are the only direct flights to such a country.

For flights with a connection:

UAE allows [airside transit without a visa](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=PK&EM=PK&DE=DE&TR=AE&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), even for Pakistani citizens. Since Dubai (and Abu Dhabi) are major international hubs, this opens up a number of travel possibilities. If you have a long layover, it is even possible to get a (landside) transit visa as part of a hotel package. Emirates or Etihad must help you book this.

From Dubai you can connect to a flight to Bahrain (e-visa), Malé, Maldives (visa on arrival), Djibouti (visa on arrival), Nairobi, Kenya (e-visa), Yangon, Myanmar (e-visa), Kathmandu, Nepal (visa on arrival), Mahe Island, Seychelles (visa on arrival), Entebbe, Uganda (visa on arrival), and Lusaka, Zambia (e-visa). These flights are mostly on Emirates and its partner airlines.

Going through Abu Dhabi offers an additional destination, Dar Es Salaam, Tanzania (visa on arrival) in addition to Bahrain, Kenya, Nepal, and Seychelles. These flights are mostly on Etihad and its partner airlines.

Another possibility is to transit via China, which will allow you to transit and even leave the airport during your layover if necessary. A [trip to Jeju Island is possible](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=PK&DE=KR&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=CN&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) if you transit via PEK. That routing, on PIA and KAL airlines, is LHE-PEK-CJU, and only a few rupees more than the cheapest flights that have more stops. This avoids itineraries that pass through Seoul and any possible delays or confusion at immigration there.

With two flight connections it may be possible to reach the various Caribbean islands which allow visa-free or visa on arrival entry to Pakistani nationals, but I wasn't able to find a suitable transit airport from a quick search. That doesn't mean one doesn't exist, though. Such a trip would be easy with a transit visa from the USA, which may be easier to obtain than a tourist visa. The US generally issues multiple entry visas good for up to five years (for both tourism/business and transit) to Pakistani nationals, so you can obtain this well in advance of any holiday which might require it.

Comment: *Male* you mean Mali ?

Comment: @blackbird No, I mean [_Malé_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mal%C3%A9), the capital of [Maldives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maldives).