# Jeju island visa requirements for Pakistani

Tags: visas, south-korea, pakistani-citizens

I am planning to visit to Jeju Island, Korea, for vacation (5 to 6 days) with my friends. Is there any specific visa requirement for me and my friends traveling from Pakistan to Jeju?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **don't** need a visa for a visit to Jeju Island.

> Foreigners can enter Jeju Island without Korean Visa for the purpose of transit and tour as follows:
>
> - Flying to Jeju island through a direct flight from the place of departure
> - Flying to Jeju island through the same airport, without transferring to another airport for connecting flight to Jeju island
>
> Please be notified that foreigners should hold Korean visa when transferring to another airport for a connecting flight to Jeju Island:

Source: [Ministry of Foreign Affairs, Republic of Korea](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/ph-cebu-en/brd/m_2260/view.do?seq=721075&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=4)

> **Visa-free Entry to Jeju: 180 Countries.**
>
> (Only 11 countries are required to apply for a visa: Afghanistan, Cuba, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Libya, Nigeria, Macedonia, Palestine, Sudan, and Syria)
>   Duration of stay: Up to 30 days
>
> Conditions of entry:
>
> - Those that arrive directly into Jeju island by flights or ships.
> - A Chinese tourist group arriving at the Incheon International Airport, who intends to travel to Seoul and Gyeongggi Province within 12 or 24 hours and then go to the Jeju island by transferring to the domestic flight. (Domestic connecting flight) - (Hereinafter referred to as 'group transit passenger to Jeju)
> - For a group transit passenger to Jeju, a person must join a tour program of Korean travel agents that serve Chinese tourists groups only and that are designated by the Ministry of Culture, Sports, and Tourism, and the Chinese travel agents in charge of a group visa application at the Korean embassy or Consulate General in China. Also, a group transit passenger must hold a domestic airline ticket to the Jeju Island in which a flight departs within 12 or 24 hours (Source: Korean Immigration Office, www.hikorea.go.kr)

Source: [ICCJEJU](http://www.iccjeju.co.kr/EN/AboutJeju/AccessAndVisa)

Comment: Pakistani citizens can transit to/from Jeju Island [via China](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76407/3221).